# re.split выводит не то что задумывалось(python3.6.1)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

```
from re import *
v=split(r"[\s,)(]", r"(C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\сайты.txt,C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg)")
print(v)
```

Код выводит:

`['', 'C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\сайты.txt', 'C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg', '']`

А должен выводить:

`['C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\сайты.txt', 'C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg']`

Почему так выводит?

Comment: `strip()` примените первоначально к строке, что ли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы обрезаете по заданным литералам, **именно это и делает питон**, с одной стороны литерала `C`, а с другой? Ничего - пустая строка, вот он ее и вставляет.

Что бы получить то что вам нужно, вы должны сказать питону **что вы хотите получить**, а не *что вам не нужно*.

В комментариях @gil9red предложил более правильное регулярное выражение:
 `r"\w.+?\.\w+"`

```
import re

string = r"(C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\сайты.txt,C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg)"
regex = r"([\w\:\\\.\-]+)"

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

[Живой пример](https://repl.it/repls/TrainedHopefulMoth)

Comment: У меня такая регулярка получилась: `r"\w:.+?\.\w+"`. Пример: https://regex101.com/r/PXSQx3/1

Comment: @gil9red, Ваша даже лучше, с небольшой оговоркой "\w.+?\.\w+" двоеточие не нужно. Добавлю его в ответ.

Comment: Двоеточие указывал для буквы диска `C:`, `D:`

Comment: @gil9red вы уже указываете `.+?`. Двоеточие здесь избыточно, да и в любом случае вы его не экранируете, оно не делает то что вы ожидаете.

Comment: Регулярку я писал руководствуясь тем, что хочу найти пути файлов от начала и до конца, началом является буква диска (`\w:`), после я ищу не жадно все символы (`.+?`) до конца файла, по его суффиксу (`\.\w+`). Поэтому не считаю что тут избыточность. Понятно, что суффикс такой можно и в названии папки встретить, но ограничения должны быть. Вообще, по поводу избыточности, тот же результат можно достигнуть еще проще. Я покажу в ответе

Comment: @gil9red, Я говорю о том что если вы уберете двоеточие, то результат не изменится. Скажу честно, без регулярного выражение решать такую задачу плохо, вы допускаете ту же ошибку что и автор. Вы обрезаете то что не нужно, вместо того что бы просить необходимое. Это плохо по тому что такой подход с высокой долей вероятности более зависим от входных данных.

Comment: Да я понял это, когда прочитал про избыточность, но и наглядность тоже важна, регулярки и так почти не читаемы, что их адептам порой новую проще написать, чем понять текущую. Поэтому и я двоеточие оставил. Ваша регулярка ищет, `все, кроме`, поэтому вам нужно описать все символы, что могут быть в путях к файлу. Это минус вашего регулярного выражения и оно сломается, если будут строки с символом, который не покрывает регулярка, например: `r"(C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\сайты.txt,C://Users/,C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg)"`

Comment: @gil9red, Понимаю, именно по этому в своем ответе я предложил Вашу и сразу же сказал что Ваша лучше)

Comment: Руководствоваться нужно теми данными, что уже есть. Поэтому в данном случае, разбиение по символу не хуже и не лучше сбора "всех символов кроме"

Answer (score 1):

В простых случаях обработки текста, можно без регулярок обойтись:

```
text = r"(C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\сайты.txt,C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg)"
filename_list = text[1:-1].split(',')
print(filename_list)
```

Результат:

```
['C:\\Users\\Gleb\\Desktop\\сайты.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Gleb\\Desktop\\istock_000020116885large_-_copy-700x461.jpg']
```